# Details View Control only displaying one record for ASP.NET Web SIte

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm sure there is an easy answer for this, but why when using a details view control in my page that is bound to an access data source, why is only the first record of my table being displayed?

When I bind a drop down list to the same data source the drop down list displays all records within my table.

On another page I used a data list and it displayed all records for the select statement I created.

Do I need a for loop to load each record into a details view control?

Thanks for any suggestions and sorry for the noob question.

Edit: Here is the code for the page I'am refering too

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"            Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" 
            DataValueField="ProductID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/Halloween.mdb" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Name] FROM [Products]">
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
            DataKeyNames="ProductID">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="ProductID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" 
                    SortExpression="CategoryID" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/Halloween.mdb" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Name], [CategoryID] FROM [Products] ORDER BY [CategoryID]">
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It could be several things. Can you post some details or code?

Comment: I have discovered the answer, DetailsView Controls don't by default behave the same as a drop down list or a ListView Control when bound to a data source. DetailView controls typically present one record from a table at a time. You Can "enable Paging" which allows one to set the pager settings so that hyperlinks will navigate you through each record. Hopefully my discovery will help someone else in future.

Comment: You can make an answer with that information -- It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, wasn't sure if it was acceptable to answer one's own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the answer, DetailsView Controls don't by default behave the same as a drop down list or a ListView Control when bound to a data source. DetailView controls typically present one record from a table at a time. You Can "Enable Paging" which allows one to set the "Pager Settings" so that hyperlinks will navigate you through each record in the table. Hopefully my discovery will help someone else in future.

Here is the code for the DetailsView Control and how it looks different than the notation above.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
            DataKeyNames="ProductID" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False">
            <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="ProductID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" 
                    SortExpression="CategoryID" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/Halloween.mdb" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Name], [CategoryID] FROM [Products] ORDER BY [CategoryID]">
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```